# Telegram API Ask for User Confirmation

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to make a basic User Prompt in python-telegram-bot that asks a user a confirmation of `Yes` or `No`. `Yes` will continue execution and `No` will just do nothing.

I can currently make the prompt by doing

```
keyboard = [
    [InlineKeyboardButton(u"Yes", callback_data=???)],
    [InlineKeyboardButton(u"No", callback_data=???)]
]
reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
```

But what do I set the `callback_data` as? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Anything can be.

Comment: @Sean: What does that mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set there whatever you want, than you check for that value

take a look for this example 
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinekeyboard.py